# medialibrary.sqlitedb - any ideas on how to edit and view?

Tags: iphone, ipad, sqlite, ipod, media-library

Does anyone have ANY leads on the iPhone/iPad/iPod `MediaLibrary.sqlitedb` in `/var/mobile/media/iTunes_Control/iTunes`? I have found no leads on google and figured now the iPhone has been around for some time, someone somewhere knows something about this database.
Some SQLite browsers can list the database structure, but i have found none so far that can list the actual data. Please help me!

Comment: Did you get any further with this?

Answer (score 0):

Use SQLite Studio, it can reads also values in the DB.

Answer (score 0):

the sqlite3 command line tool can read everything as well. seems like anything supporting sqlite version 3 should be able to as well (perl/python/ruby/etc libs).

```
$ file ./iTunes_Control/iTunes/MediaLibrary.sqlitedb
./iTunes_Control/iTunes/MediaLibrary.sqlitedb: SQLite 3.x database, user version 1140116
$ sudo apt-get install sqlite3 # ubuntu/debian
$ sqlite3 ./iTunes_Control/iTunes/MediaLibrary.sqlitedb
SQLite version 3.7.13 2012-06-11 02:05:22
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> .databases
seq  name             file                                                      
---  ---------------  ----------------------------------------------------------
0    main             /media/ipod/./iTunes_Control/iTunes/MediaLibrary.sqlitedb 
sqlite> .dump
PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE genius_config (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, version INTEGER UNIQUE, default_num_results INTEGER DEFAULT 0, min_num_results INTEGER DEFAULT 0, data BLOB);
...[snip]...
```